# Scalability vs performance

Tags: operating-system

How is performance against scalability?

I have this text from the book Distributed Systems by Tanenbaum:

"Scalability of a system can be measured along at least three different dimensions (Neuman, 1994). First, a system can be scalable with respect to its size, meaning that we can easily add more users and resources to the system. Second, a geographically scalable system is one in which the users and resources may lie far apart. Third, a system can be administratively scalable, meaning that it can still be easy to manage even if it spans many independent administrative organizations. Unfortunately, a system that is scalable in one or more of these dimensions often exhibits some loss of performance as the system scales up."

I thought performance increase when scalability scales up. Since for example when the number of resources increase performance also should be increased. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: On a monolith system you would have all components on one machine. The communication between components of a system happens directly on the hardware the system is running on. You would eventually have too many requests which would cause a bottleneck due to hardware limitations. So when that problem arises you will split the components on multiple hardware to split and reduce the load you had before. Now the components of the system are decoupled and distributed and can not communicate directly anymore. You will have a http layer between (usually a rest api) and the time one component needs to return a result is now also increased and not deterministic due to the network between those components

Comment: If  a system scales up administratively, can you please explain how performance decrease?

Comment: If you scale a system up administratively then you usually have to offer multiple interfaces which would result in additional complexity and external dependencies. This could lead to performance decrease but does not have to, it all depends on the use case. You could introduce for example a service that pulls configuration data from external sources which are managed by other organizations. You would now have an administrative support but decreased performance due to the dependency of the external sources compared to a system that has its config data on its machine